# Degree of minimal polynomial of $e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}\sqrt[3]{2}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, minimal-polynomials

I want to know the degree of the minimal polynomial of $e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}\sqrt[3]{2}$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$.

It has to be 3, right? Since $a = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}\sqrt[3]{2}$ we get the polynomial $a^3-2$; or am I missing something crucial here?

Answer (score 5):

Actually it is $2$. It can't be $3$, because $x^3-2$ is not irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$, since it has a root; and it can't be $1$ as $e^{\frac{2i\pi}{3}}\sqrt[3]{2}\notin\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$.